# Gap between border and image when border radius is added

Tags: html, image, css

I have an image with a border radius of 50% and a 3px border around it.
My problem is when the border radius is given, there is a 1px gap between the image and the border.

Issue is demonstrated in the below image.

[image]

And the css I'm using,

```
img {
    border: 3px solid #4CB7AC;
    height: 46px;
    width: 46px;
    border-radius:50%;
}
```

Note that

- The image size is 46px X 46px. Not resized.
- And I HAVE to use `<img>` to get the image. Setting it as a background image is ruled out.
- Solution must be compatible with all browsers. Even IE8.

Is there a way to remove that gap?

EDIT
 [JS Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/uW2Pa/4/)

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle example?

Comment: Are you expecting `border-raidus` to work in IE8?

Comment: `46x46` is a small size, I don't think almost people can see the gap at normal level of zoom. So it's not really a serious problem. If it's important to you, you can try placing some overlaying div to cover the gap.

Comment: I don't see the issue even when I zoom : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/5Y5mR/

Comment: ie8 has no border-radius support unless you use something like this: http://css3pie.com/documentation/pie-js/

Comment: i see no gap too: http://jsfiddle.net/omegaiori/9rXdF/ it must be something "around" that img that produces the gap

Comment: JS Fiddle added.
As for IE8 support for border radius is not the main concern, but the gap appearing in all the other browsers when the border radius is given.
This is most visible when the background color is black or some other dark shade.

Comment: @ShanthaKumara In your fiddle your image has a small black border as some of the pixels are half black half blue in order to make the edge appear smoother, anti-aliased. Try making the image square, filled all the way.

Comment: @Mathias Even if you change the image the problem is still there.
Note that the problem is visible on images which are light when the background is a darker shade. Meaning that there is a space between the border and the image.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just Add `Background color` same as your Border color and it's fixed.

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uW2Pa/9/)

Comment: what about `background-image` ?

Comment: This is a trick, not a solution.

Answer (score 6):

The `background-color` suggestion works great, but if you're in a situation where a background color would be less than ideal (for example a PNG image with a bt of transparency) then you might be able to use `background-clip: border-box;`

See [background-clip on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) for more details about that property.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing it like this :

```
img {
    border: 3px solid #4CB7AC;
    height: 46px;
    width: 46px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 46px 46px 46px 46px;
    border-radius: 46px 46px 46px 46px;
}
```

Also, for IE8 and lower try using Conditional Comments to replace the border radius and add a generic .png image

```
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
Image source 
 <![endif]-->
```

**UPDATE**

That GAP you see is a "bug" of using border-radius, you can also try fixing it by adding an image background color same as the border color:

```
img {
        border: 3px solid #4CB7AC;
        height: 46px;
        width: 46px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 46px 46px 46px 46px;
        border-radius: 46px 46px 46px 46px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #4CB7AC;
    }
```

Comment: The image is dynamic. To be more clear the image is a user profile image the users are going to upload. So we can't have the image be the same color as the border.

Comment: You will not have the image the same color, the background color will be placed under your image, therefore removing the gap, i posted another answer with a working jsFiddle so you can wee what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `font-size:0` to `img` should fix your problem.

Comment: hacks are NOT solutions

Answer (score 0):

without overflow:hide
use LEFT and Top also height equal to parent

```
      min-height: 52px;
      bottom: 1px;
      left: 0.5px;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can try this at the top of your `CSS` file:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

It will remove that gap. To keep picture from shrinking you can add to your `img` class this CSS rule: `object-fit: cover;`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should add a class to your img tag:

```
<img src="/image.png" class="img-author">
```

Otherwise, it will change all images in your website.

You can fix this small gap using the "object-fit" css attribute.

```css
img.img-author{
    border: 3px solid #4CB7AC;
    height: 46px;
    width: 46px;
    border-radius:50%;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a5c9fa2dbf60eb47b3c0e17eaa43d889?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" class="img-author">
```