# CSS - How to remove thin white line between :after element and blue border on hover on image

Tags: html, css

This is my structure:

```
<div class="parent">
<a href="#">
  <p class="carousel_img">
    <span class="img"></span>   
    Some text
  </p>
</a>
```

and this is my style:

```
.parent{
  height: 270px;
  width: 270px;
}
.img {
    background-image: url(http://frontendtest.ru/anit/img/ps_3.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    display: block;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.carousel_img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 4px solid #f6e9d6;
    height: 260px;
    width: 260px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
a:hover .carousel_img {
    border-color: #2e8ce4;
}
.carousel_img:before {
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    border-left: 2px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    margin: auto;
    bottom: 20px;
    z-index: 2;
}
.carousel_img:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: none;
}
.carousel_img:after {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 56px;
    background: #2e8ce4;
}
a:hover .carousel_img:before, a:hover .carousel_img:after {
    display: block;
}
```

In Chrome, Firefox, Edge we can see a thin white line between blue :after element and blue border on bottom of picture when we :hover on image. This is a link on my pen http://codepen.io/DmitryShutov/pen/JKovYb.
How can I remove thin white line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gap between border and image when border radius is added](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23490320/gap-between-border-and-image-when-border-radius-is-added)