# Gap between border and child element with border radius

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement radio buttons which kind of work like segmented controls:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  background-color: brown;
  width: 80vw;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 2rem solid skyblue;
  border-radius: 999px;
}

label {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 2rem;
  border-radius: 999px;
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

input:checked + label {
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <input type="radio" id="hello" name="test" checked />
    <label for="hello">Hello</label>
    
    <input type="radio" id="world" name="test" />
    <label for="world">World</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, there's an annoying gap of about 1px between the nested label and the parent div:

[image: image showing gap between nested elements with border radii]

This issue is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23490320/gap-between-border-and-image-when-border-radius-is-added), but the workarounds suggested don't really work for my use case since I can't change the background color. I'm also curious if this is a browser bug or some kind of anti-aliasing issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just add box shadow to the input:check + label

```
input:checked + label {
    background-color: skyblue;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0 1px skyblue;
}
```

Link to [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Arham11/7nrwcye8/2/)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the reason why you are getting that 1 px gap but you can add "transform: translateX(-1px);" to shift it left by 1px. This can work as a temp solution.

```
  label {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 2rem;
    border-radius: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateX(-1px);
  }
```

Comment: Cool, so this works as well, and another solution is adding `margin-left: -1px` to `label:first-of-type` and `margin-right: -1px` to `label:last-of-type`, but I think the `box-shadow` approach is a bit cleaner since you don't have to think about layout.

Comment: yeah, but I still don't understand why we are having that annoying gap. These are just temporary fixes

Answer (score 0):

Change `label` `border-radius` `999px` to `35px`

```
label {
      flex: 1;
      padding: 2rem;
      border-radius: 35px;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  background-color: brown;
  width: 80vw;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 2rem solid skyblue;
  border-radius: 999px;
}

label {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 2rem;
  border-radius: 35px;
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

input:checked + label {
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <input type="radio" id="hello" name="test" checked />
    <label for="hello">Hello</label>
    
    <input type="radio" id="world" name="test" />
    <label for="world">World</label>
  </div>
</div>
```